# NameError after importing a file

Tags: python

I have two files. One called "variables.py" with this function in:

```
def get_players():
    '''
    (NoneType) -> Dictionary
    Asks for player names
    '''
    loop = True
    players = {}
    while loop == True:
        player = input("Enter player names: ")
        player = player.strip()
        if player in players or player == "":
            print("Choose a different name!")
        elif "player1" in players:
            players["player2"] = [player, 0]
        elif player not in players:
            players["player1"] = [player, 0]
        if len(players) >= 2:
            loop = False
    return players
```

And another file in the same directory called "game.py" with this inside:

```
import variables
players = get_players()
```

When i try to run "game.py" i get this error`NameError: name 'get_players' is not defined`
why?! I have tried everything!

Comment: I think you can either do `from variables import *` or try `variables.get_players()`.  The `import *` means import everything, so it could also be targeted by saying `import get_players`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
players = variables.get_players()
```

Since you have imported only the module `variables`, and not the method `get_players`.

Or you could also do:

```
from variables import get_players

players = get_players()
```

Read more on [importing modules here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Answer (score 1):

You have imported `variables`, not `get_players`. You can either keep the import as it is and call `variables.get_players()`, or do `from variables import get_players` and then call `get_players()`.

This is a fairly fundamental thing in Python: looks like you could benefit from a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

With Python, when you import a module, a module variable is created of that name which is where all the imported module's variables live:

```
import variables
players = variables.get_players()
```

You can also import *from* a module which will just introduce that name by itself:

```
from variables import get_players
players = get_players()
```

You can also do the following to import *all* names from a module, but it is discouraged because it leads to hard-to-read code:

```
from variables import *
players = get_players()
```